# How to multiply a pandas dataframe with a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, pca

I have a simple program for performing PCA analysis on a dataset. The goal is to multiply the dataset by the feature vector at the end of the program.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA


def main():
    s = pd.read_csv('A1-dm.csv')
    s = pca(s)

def pca(s):
    # Normalize each s
    A1 = s[['A1']].to_numpy()
    A2 = s[['A2']].to_numpy()
    
    print(A1.ndim)
    if 'A3' in s:
        A3 = s[['A3']].to_numpy()
        A3_norm = A3/np.linalg.norm(A3)

    A1_norm = A1/np.linalg.norm(A1)
    A2_norm = A2/np.linalg.norm(A2)

    data = np.array([A1_norm,A2_norm])
    if 'A3' in s:
        data = np.array([A1_norm,A2_norm,A3_norm]).squeeze()

    # determine covariance
    covMatrix = np.cov(data,bias=True)
    print(covMatrix)

    # compute eigen vactors and eigenvalues
    w, v = LA.eig(covMatrix)
    print("eigen vectors")
    print(v)

    print("eigen values")
    print(w)

    varianceV = np.empty(3)

    # calculate variances
    varianceV[0] = w[0]/(w[0]+w[1]+w[2])
    varianceV[1] = w[1]/(w[0]+w[1]+w[2])
    varianceV[2] = w[2]/(w[0]+w[1]+w[2])


    print(f' variance of v1 : {varianceV[0]}')
    print(f' variance of v2 : {varianceV[1]}')
    print(f' variance of v3 : {varianceV[2]}')

    # calculate feature vector
    v_initial = 0
    featureVector = np.empty(3)
    for i in range(0,3):
        if varianceV[i] > v_initial:
            featureVector = v[i]

    print(f'feature vector: {featureVector}')
    resolved_dataset = np.concatenate(featureVector,s.to_numpy())
    print(f'dataset = {resolved_dataset}')

main()
```

Expected:
The 3x3 matrix consisting of A1, A2, A3 columns should be multiplied by the 3x1 vector such that the returned dataset has been transformed via the principle components.

Actual:

```
2
[[ 2.22742836e-03 -1.08176619e-04  1.28813346e-03]
 [-1.08176619e-04  2.37308545e-03 -5.81124131e-05]
 [ 1.28813346e-03 -5.81124131e-05  7.48662113e-04]]
eigen vectors
[[-0.50114911 -0.84926886  0.16610832]
 [-0.0016557   0.19289331  0.98121834]
 [ 0.86535936 -0.49146168  0.09807444]]
eigen values
[2.78617954e-06 2.99742571e-03 2.34896403e-03]
 variance of v1 : 0.0005208614522544459
 variance of v2 : 0.5603528012046752
 variance of v3 : 0.4391263373430704
feature vector: [ 0.86535936 -0.49146168  0.09807444]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\cov.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\cov.py", line 8, in main
    s = pca(s)
  File ".\cov.py", line 59, in pca
    resolved_dataset = np.concatenate(featureVector,s.to_numpy())
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Here is a sample of the dataset

```
A1,A2,A3,Class
2,0.4631338,1.5,3
8,0.7460648,3.0,3
6,0.264391038,2.5,2
5,0.4406713,2.3,1
2,0.410438159,1.5,3
2,0.302901816,1.5,2
6,0.275869396,2.5,3
8,0.084782428,3.0,3
2,0.53226533,1.5,2
8,0.070034818,2.9,1
2,0.668631847,1.5,2
2,0.215622639,1.5,2
2,0.148916231,1.5,3
2,0.51335434,1.5,3
```

Any help figuring out how to perform this operation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I think you are not using the correct data for your process, from my point of view, you should use np.matmul and `data` variable instead of `s`: `resolved_dataset = np.matmul(featureVector, data)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you simply want to multiple the feature vector with each of the columns in your dataset, i.e. `0.865 * 2`, `-0.491 * 0.463`, and, `0.098 * 1.5`. This can simply be done by using the `*` sign:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
feature_vector = [0.8653593, -0.49146168, 0.09807444]

df[["A1", "A2", "A3"]] = df[["A1", "A2", "A3"]] * feature_vector
```

Which returns the following dataframe:

| A1 | A2 | A3 | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.73072 | -0.227613 | 0.147112 | 3 |
| 6.92287 | -0.366662 | 0.294223 | 3 |
| 5.19216 | -0.129938 | 0.245186 | 2 |
| 4.3268 | -0.216573 | 0.225571 | 1 |
| 1.73072 | -0.201715 | 0.147112 | 3 |